# Django 1.5 + django-ajax-upload-widget - jQuery $.ajax handle success response as error

Tags: django, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ripple, mezzanine

I'm using django 1.5 + Mezzanine + [django-ajax-upload-widget](https://github.com/zmathew/django-ajax-upload-widget). I have the problem with the django-ajax-upload-widget.

So, when I trying to choose file in form I have an upload error. As I undestand (by using js debugger) - the problem is that jQuery use error handler to handle successful response.

So here is the view, which process ajax uploading:

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def upload(request):
  form = UploadedFileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
    uploaded_file = form.save()
    data = {'path': uploaded_file.file.url,}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
  else:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest(simplejson.dumps({'errors': form.errors}))
```

I also tried python debugger, so file uploading cause running of this line:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

So, it means that file uploaded successfuly (I also checked destination folder - it contains this file). Using `HttpResponse` means that status of request is 200, as I understand. So, jQuery run `error` handler instead of `success`. So. it means that the problem may appear when jQuery try to process data, but here is js code:

```
$.ajax(this.$element.data('upload-url'), {
  iframe: true,
  files: this.$element,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { self.uploadDone(data); },
  error: function(data) { self.uploadFail(data); }
});
```

So, `processData: false` and here is no proccessing.

How do you think - what may cause the problem? And how to fix it?

**ADDITION:**

I changed error handler to

```
AjaxUploadWidget.prototype.uploadFail = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  if(this.options.onError) {
    this.options.onError.call(this);
  } else {
    console.log('Upload failed:');
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
};
```

So, js console shows that it is "parsererror".

**Problem SOLVED**

I try to `console.log(jqXHR.responseText);` in error handler and see the following:

```
if (window.top.ripple) { window.top.ripple("bootstrap").inject(window, document); }{"path": "/static/media/ajax_uploads/c351360b8aa7417b89f51cdd9e9057ae-Koala.jpg"}
```

But I MUST see just this:

```
{"path": "/static/media/ajax_uploads/c351360b8aa7417b89f51cdd9e9057ae-Koala.jpg"}
```

So, I turn off Ripple plugin in my Chrome and all works fine o_O :-)

But it's very strange that some plugin can break the work of frontend js. Do you have any thoughts on this?